# efficient SQL query on single table for Date Difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have a SQL Table (TEST) containing Test Name and Last Updated Date time. The Last Updated date time is updated every 5 minutes through external Services. I have a service which runs every minute to loop all the rows in the table every minute and find if the difference between the Last updated date time and current date time is less than or equal to 5 mins , else, i need to select those records. The table will have maximum of 500 records. is there any efficient SQL Query to retrieve those records other than looping one by one? Suggestions or comments highly appreciated.

Sample Data

```
TestName    LastUpdated
Test1       2017-07-25 11:30:33
Test2       2017-07-25 11:20:12
Test3       2017-07-25 11:27:14
Test4       2017-07-25 11:17:18
```

If i consider current time is 2017-07-25 11:31:00,

Output

```
Test2
Test4
```

Because the difference between current date and their LastUpdated is greater than 5 minutes.

Comment: Which records exactly get selected if the difference is not less than or equal to 5 minutes?  Which database are you using (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) ?

Comment: I need the records greater than 5 minutes. i'm using SQL server 2012. Thanks

Comment: So do you _always_ want to select all records which are more than 5 minutes old?  Can you show us some sample data which demonstrates what you have in mind?

Comment: I have edited my post to add sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just compare the timestamp of each record against the current timestamp and then retain those records which are within 5 minutes of now:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE LastUpdate > DATEADD(minute, -5, current_timestamp)
```

Comment: I think, if there is index od `LastUpdate` column, it won't be used. Should not be better to use `WHERE LastUpdate > DATEADD(minute, -5, current_timestam)` instead?